# How do I solve SIGABRT "Abort with payload" with no error message?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am very new to Swift so I apologise if my question may sound obvious, but I looked everywhere and could not find any solutions for my issue. I know there are other similar questions to mine, it is really not my intention to make a duplicate, but I believe I needed to make a new question because none of the answers to said similar questions have solved my problem, it appears to me to be a different kind of issue and I would love to receive some help.

I have been trying to develop this app which has been running just fine in the simulator in the past few weeks. However, I need to try it out on my iOS device to try some features that involve the use of a camera. The problem is that the app crashes on launch every single time. I tried to download another app from GitHub, a simple one that doesn't involve the use of pods, and it runs fine on the same iOS device. It's just my app that doesn't. Here's the error on crash:

```html
dyld`__abort_with_payload:
    0x102dab5dc <+0>:  mov    x16, #0x209
    0x102dab5e0 <+4>:  svc    #0x80
->  0x102dab5e4 <+8>:  b.lo   0x102dab600               ; <+36>
    0x102dab5e8 <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x102dab5ec <+16>: mov    x29, sp
    0x102dab5f0 <+20>: bl     0x102da9be8               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x102dab5f4 <+24>: mov    sp, x29
    0x102dab5f8 <+28>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #0x10
    0x102dab5fc <+32>: ret    
    0x102dab600 <+36>: ret    

dyld`_dyld_start:
    0x102d61000 <+0>:   mov    x28, sp
    0x102d61004 <+4>:   and    sp, x28, #0xfffffffffffffff0
    0x102d61008 <+8>:   mov    x0, #0x0
    0x102d6100c <+12>:  mov    x1, #0x0
    0x102d61010 <+16>:  stp    x1, x0, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x102d61014 <+20>:  mov    x29, sp
    0x102d61018 <+24>:  sub    sp, sp, #0x10             ; =0x10 
    0x102d6101c <+28>:  ldr    x0, [x28]
    0x102d61020 <+32>:  ldr    x1, [x28, #0x8]
    0x102d61024 <+36>:  add    x2, x28, #0x10            ; =0x10 
    0x102d61028 <+40>:  adrp   x3, -1
    0x102d6102c <+44>:  add    x3, x3, #0x0              ; =0x0 
    0x102d61030 <+48>:  mov    x4, sp
    0x102d61034 <+52>:  bl     0x102d6107c               ; dyldbootstrap::start(dyld3::MachOLoaded const*, int, char const**, dyld3::MachOLoaded const*, unsigned long*)
->  0x102d61038 <+56>:  mov    x16, x0
    0x102d6103c <+60>:  ldr    x1, [sp]
    0x102d61040 <+64>:  cmp    x1, #0x0                  ; =0x0 
    0x102d61044 <+68>:  b.ne   0x102d61050               ; <+80>
    0x102d61048 <+72>:  add    sp, x28, #0x8             ; =0x8 
    0x102d6104c <+76>:  br     x16
    0x102d61050 <+80>:  mov    x30, x1
    0x102d61054 <+84>:  ldr    x0, [x28, #0x8]
    0x102d61058 <+88>:  add    x1, x28, #0x10            ; =0x10 
    0x102d6105c <+92>:  add    x2, x1, x0, lsl #3
    0x102d61060 <+96>:  add    x2, x2, #0x8              ; =0x8 
    0x102d61064 <+100>: mov    x3, x2
    0x102d61068 <+104>: ldr    x4, [x3]
    0x102d6106c <+108>: add    x3, x3, #0x8              ; =0x8 
    0x102d61070 <+112>: cmp    x4, #0x0                  ; =0x0 
    0x102d61074 <+116>: b.ne   0x102d61068               ; <+104>
    0x102d61078 <+120>: br     x16
```

[Here's a picture of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJsbr.png)

I have been searching all over the internet for this question and I've tried all the possible solutions, but with no success. Again, perhaps it's because of my lack of experience... but here's what I have tried so far:

- I added the frameworks in the tab target > general, with no success.
  [Here's a picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOdDC.png)
- I changed the frameworks' status to "Optional" in the tab build phases > link binary with libraries.
  [Here's a picture of that, too.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzhpe.png)
- If I change it to "embed & sign", it gives me multiple errors like these, one for each framework:
  [Both red,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0b4Kb.png)
  [and yellow errors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2D8pR.png)
- If I go to run > diagnostics, guard malloc & thread sanitizer are already unticked:
  [Here's my stats.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07jxw.png)
- At one point, I was desperate enough to try and delete all the frameworks files lol (I obviously did so in a duplicate project) and it was disastrous.
- The trust settings of my certificates in the keychain are all set to System Defaults.
- My info.plist does have "Privary - Camera Usage Description", type String.

If it makes any difference, I use pods for Firebase and IQKeyboardManagerSwift. I say this because I noticed how most of the custom frameworks have the name of the pods (don't laugh at me please, I literally started coding like last month lol!). However one thing that isn't really clear to me is why these frameworks are greyed out in the Navigator, maybe that could be the problem? Again, I have no idea... plus, I have some frameworks in the pods section (see below), and at least a hundred in the app section, below the "info.plist" file and the "GoogleService-Info.plist" file. Is that even normal?

[Frameworks in the app section;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwDuY.jpg)
[Frameworks in the pods section.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2y6pv.png)

I think I said a lot but if any information is missing please let me know. I want to thank everybody in advance for any help you may be able to provide, I am so desperate to solve this!

PS: I am not even allowed to enter images yet, I hope you can check the links, though!

Comment: What version of Xcode?  Are you using a free developer account?

Comment: @PhillipMills hi and thank you for answering! My XCode is Version 11.3 (11C29) and the account I'm using is my own personal. It's the same one I use for my personal Apple Store, so to speak. I do not own a developer account yet! Do you think this could have something to do with the problem I'm facing? The other app I downloaded from GitHub worked just fine although it was registered to the same account.

Comment: @PhillipMills update: I just updated my XCode to Version 11.3.1 (11C504), but the error is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally forgot to update this, but I solved by updating my phone to 13.4 (which is still a beta version) and my xcode too (also beta version). It seems that the problem is the previous/current update, not sure why but it solved the problem for me. Hope it can save someone else some headache.

Comment: Exact same problem here... iOS version 15.3.1(iPad) and Xcode version: 13.2.1